# What are the major differences between the Pixel 7 and 7a?

Tags: google-pixel

I'm currently in the market to change my phone, and I'm looking for a Google Pixel: [Which Pixel phone is right for you?](https://store.google.com/ca/magazine/compare_pixel?hl=en-CA&selections=eyJtOSI6ImNHbDRaV3hmTnc9PSIsIlNpIjpbWyIyIiwiTVE9PSJdLFsiMSIsIk1USTQiXV0sImI5IjoiVEhkMGRVRmoifQ%3D%3D)

And right now I just dont get what are the differences between the Pixel 7a and the 7

Personally, I only see a screen that is .2in less, and everything else is pretty much the same, except that the 7a is 200$ less.

So what are the major differences between the 7 and 7a that I'm obviously missing that would explain that 200$ difference?

Comment: See https://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=11903&idPhone2=12170

Comment: I mean just like the comparator of Google, most of that is very technical and not being that big in the world of phones, I have no idea what most of it means. I need a little bit of ELI5

Comment: Like the only other thing I saw was wireless charge, and that wired charged has 2W less.  (20/18) So I guess the 7a charges a little slower but still, is it that huge a difference?

Comment: AFAIK, Pixel 7a and Pixel 7 differences are very little, compared to Pixel 6a and Pixel 6. Most reviews about Pixel 7a also explain the differences from Pixel 7 ([XDA](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-pixel-7a-review/), [Android Police](https://www.androidpolice.com/google-pixel-7a-review/), [GSM Arena](https://www.gsmarena.com/google_pixel_7a-review-2573.php))

Comment: So the answer is: there pretty much are none.